# How to use a custom login script to access my wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way I can use my custom login script and table of users and passwords to access my restricted wordpress site. Am currently using password-protected plugin but its not ideal. I want to use my own table with users and passwords to access the site. Is there a way or a plugin where I can import my users and use that to access my wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import only users into database then try instructions on following article.

https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-membership/how-to-bulk-upload-member-details-from-a-csv-file-243